# Работа с QProcess

Tags: qt

Пишу IDE для собственного простенького языка программирования с интерпретатором. Когда в голову пришла идея получать вывод от интерпретатора и перенаправлять его в IDE, решил использовать QProcess. Получить вывод получается, но в интерпретаторе также предусмотрен и ввод данных. Но, как сами понимаете, ввод есть не всегда, да и вводить что-то иногда нужно несколько раз. Итак, вопрос: можно ли как-то получить информацию, требуется ли процессу ввод данных?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы узнать нужен ли ввод второму приложению вам от него надо получать сообщение или сигнал - то есть вы можете читать вывод и по запросу на ввод подавать не вход данные. Либо организовать общение между приложениями через d-bus. Тогда по необходимости интерпретатор будет слать сообщения-запросы на ввод основной программе.